# Find substring in string with iterators

Tags: c++, string, iterator, find

I have a substring defined by two iterators (`start` and `end`). I need to check if this substring is present in another string.

Is there a standard library algorithm or string member I can use or adapt to do this without creating a whole new string object (`std::string(start, end)`) just for this purpose?

e.g.

```
struct Substring
{
    std::string::const_iterator start, end;
};

auto found = std::contains(whole.begin(), whole.end(), substring.start, substring.end); // ???
```

Comment: `Boost` has `boost::algorithm::contains` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.predicate_hpp

Comment: FWIW, there's soon going to be a couple of new search methods like [Boyer-Moore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/boyer_moore_searcher) if you need something of that calibre. I know libstdc++ has implemented these already.

Answer (score 11):

[`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search)

```
bool found = 
    std::search(hay.begin(), hay.end(), needle.begin(), needle.end()) != hay.end();
```

Comment: Haha. I'm not quite sure how I forgot / missed std::search. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `std::string::find` method:

```
auto found = (whole.find(&*substring.start, 0, substring.end - substring.start)
              != std::string::npos);
```

The advantage over `std::search` is that `std::find` works on strings and can be implemented using Boyer-Moore. Sadly, that is not how gcc's libstdc++ implements it.